# How to open an accordion item in an external URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to include in my page a link to external url that contains an accordion menu.

But when I'll click in the my link, the external page must be opened in a new tab with a specific section (#section8) of the accordion menu activated.

I do not have access to this external URL to change or edit the accordion options.

Is it possible?

Tks

Comment: wheres the code ??

Comment: No, it's not possible to control the display of a website you don't control, unless the owner has built in the functionality to select a section using a query parameter or hash. If there's not a url you can hit that will display the page how you want, you're out of luck.

Comment: This will only be possible if their page already has handling for querystring parameters that open the desired section. You can't trigger actions of your design on someone else's page.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
What I need is open this URL from my site (http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/negociacao/data-center/provedores-de-servico/) with "Hewlett Packard" section active. Is this possible?